# Is there any way to send celery app.task logs into stackdriver?

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, celery, stackdriver

I tried to send celery tasks logs which is created by default logging Python module into Stackdriver (google cloud platform) but I am missing something.

At the current state, all logs pushed but I am missing logs where created inside the tasks Python files.

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, log_level):
        formatter = CustomJsonFormatter(
            '(timestamp)(level)(name)(created)(process)(msecs)(message)'
        )
        formatter.json_ensure_ascii = False
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(log_level)
        client = google.cloud.logging.Client.from_service_account_json(
           'key.json')
        # StreamHandler
        # sh = logging.StreamHandler()
        sh = CloudLoggingHandler(client)
        sh.setLevel(log_level)
        sh.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(sh)


from app.utils.logger import Logger
from celery.signals import setup_logging
@setup_logging.connect
def initialize_logger(*args, **kwargs):
    Logger(log_level=log_level)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, log_level):
        formatter = CustomJsonFormatter(
            '(timestamp)(level)(name)(created)(process)(msecs)(message)'
        )
        formatter.json_ensure_ascii = False
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(log_level)

        client = google.cloud.logging.Client.from_service_account_json(
           'key.json')
        log_handler = client.get_default_handler()
        cloud_logger = logging.getLogger("cloudLogger")
        cloud_logger.setLevel(log_level)
        cloud_logger.setFormatter(formatter)
        cloud_logger.addHandler(log_handler)
```

Comment: After commented out the following line :
# cloud_logger.setFormatter(formatter)
because produce the following error:
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'setFormatter'
I cant see any logs printed out at stackdriver, Above lines of code are implemented into initialization script of celery worker